# Why does ctree(partykit) perform worse than rpart for a large dataset?

Tags: r, rpart, party

I am trying to solve the same classification problem with the R packages `rpart` and `partykit`. I would have expected better results from `partykit::ctree` as it seems to be the more 'sophisticated' method; however, my results are slightly worse.

I have the theory that this is because `ctree` uses the p-value of some statistical test for determining splits, and my dataset is relatively large (several million rows), and therefore I get to many significant p-values. Could this be the problem? And can anyone recommend and explains which settings to use for `ctree` (and or `rpart`) when working with large datasets?

Answer (score 2):

The pre-pruning strategy based on p-values from significance tests is most useful for sample sizes for which significance tests work well. However, for very large data sets with millions of observations (as in your case) commonly used significance levels such as 5% are typically too large. In `ctree()` this can lead to some overfitting. To prevent this you can:

- Use a much lower significance level, possibly selecting the best significance level by cross-validation (or similar).
- Add a post-pruning step, e.g., based on cost-complexity pruning (as in `rpart`) or information criteria.

The former can be done relatively easily "by hand". The latter needs a little bit more work. The `lmtree()` and `glmtree()` functions in `partykit` support post-pruning based on AIC or BIC.